# É necessário barra "\" no começo de funções nativas quando usamos namespace?

Tags: php, namespace

Notei que algumas bibliotecas costumam usar em funções **nativas** do PHP o `\`, por exemplo:

```
echo \str_replace('foo', 'test', $string);
```

Eu fui testar dentro de uma classe apenas com namespace isto:

```
public function foo($string)
{
    echo \str_replace('foo', 'test', $string);
}
```

e

```
public function foo($string)
{
    echo str_replace('foo', 'test', $string);
}
```

Ambas funcionaram perfeitamente, sem problemas.

Eu entendo que quando criamos funções ou classes em um namespace será necessário a barra `\` no começo, por exemplo:

```
namespace Foo;
function test() {}
```

Usando:

```
\Foo\test();
```

Devo usar em `\` em funções **nativas** por algum motivo? Ou isto é redundante?

Comment: Talvez exista uma `str_replace()` naquele namespace, que não é o nativo da linguagem, e por esse motivo a \ é especificada para fazer a referência correta.

Comment: Antes de dar um voto negativo entenda o modelo da comunidade, leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer e http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange e se tiver algum outro motivo pro downvote justifique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A outra resposta e o comentário me ajudaram a entender o problema:

> Talvez exista uma `str_replace()` naquele namespace, que não é o nativo da linguagem, e por esse motivo a \ é especificada para fazer a referência correta. - [@Havenard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78007/%C3%89-necess%C3%A1rio-barra-no-come%C3%A7o-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-nativas-quando-usamos-namespace?rq=1#comment159187_78007)

No entanto acredito que seja necessário um exemplo para um melhor entendimento do motivo disto.

O motivo de usarmos eventualmente `\` na frente de funções nativas como por exemplo `\str_replace(...)` é porque geralmente existe uma função com mesmo nome dentro (não nativa) dentro do namespace, por exemplo:

`src/Foo/utils.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

function str_replace($a, $b, $str)
{
    //Isto chama a função nativa str_replace
    return strtolower(\str_replace($a, $b, $str));
}

function foo($a, $b, $c)
{
    //Isto chama Foo\str_replace
    return str_replace($a, $b, $c);
}
```

Usando:

```
<?php
include 'src/Foo/utils.php';

Foo\foo('a', 'b', 'abcabcabc');
```

Foi necessário adicionar `\` nesta linha `return strtolower(\str_replace($a, $b, $str));` pois se não tivesse ele iria ficar recursivamente/"infinitamente" chamando `Foo\str_replace`, pois estamos dentro de `Foo`. Se fizermos

No momento que usamos `\str_replace` chamamos a função que está fora do `namespace`, que neste caso é uma função nativa.

Mas se fizermos assim:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

function str_replace($a, $b, $str)
{
    //Isto chama Foo\str_replace novamente
    return strtolower(str_replace($a, $b, $str));
}

function foo($a, $b, $c)
{
    //Isto chama Foo\str_replace
    return str_replace($a, $b, $c);
}
```

Irá ocorrer o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Z:\web\projeto\src\Foo\utils.php on line 6

## Conclusão

Devemos usar `\` para funções nativas quando declarar outra função com mesmo nome dentro do namespace.

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar {
    function str_replace($a, $b, $c) {
         //...Algo aqui
    }

    //Aqui usamos Foo\Bar\str_replace, pois é relativo ao namespace
    echo str_replace('a', 'b', 'abc');

    //Aqui chamamos a função nativa
    echo \str_replace('a', 'b', 'abc');
}
```

Não há necessidade de usar `\` se **não** houver uma função com mesmo nome de uma *função nativa*

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar {
    //Aqui o PHP chama a função nativa pois não existe a função Foo\Bar\str_replace
    echo str_replace('a', 'b', 'abc');
}
```

*Funções não nativas* **declaras** fora de namespace devem **sempre** usar o `\` na frente se usadas dentro de um namespace diferente das *funções nativas*.

Arquivo `vendor/Foo/Bar/Baz.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar {
    class Baz {
        public function output()
        {
           echo \test(); //Mostra 'Olá mundo!'
           echo test(); //Causa erro
        }
    }
}
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php
function test() {
    echo 'Olá mundo!';
}

include 'vendor/Foo/Bar/Baz.php';

Foo\Bar\Baz::output();
```

Comment: Removi meu comentário para não gerar confusão. Se a função não estiver definida no namespace, o PHP buscará a definição global da mesma, como consta na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.fallback.php).

Answer (score 3):

Não é obrigatório, porém necessário para evitar conflito de nomes ou quando precisa acessar diretamente os nomes no escopo global.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php