# Namespaces e Use quando usar e para que servem?

Tags: php, namespace

O que são namespaces e use e quando é recomendado usar eles numa aplicação ?

Comment: Acho que isso responde bem a pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16690/3635 mesmo sendo sobre outra linguagem, agora se quer saber como implementar namespaces com "pacotes" recomendo ler isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Os *namespaces* são semelhantes em diversas linguagens de programação, tal como esta resposta explica [Como funciona namespaces no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16690/3635) (mesmo o assunto sendo uma linguagens diferente)

Faço das palavras do *Maniero* as minhas:

> **Ele não encapsula nada**
>
> Este entendimento mostra que apesar da visão que os programadores têm sobre o namespace ser um módulo, uma caixa de tipos (como indica a primeira função), na realidade ele funciona como um sobrenome para para os tipos. Um sobrenome funciona como uma forma de nomear uma família. Assim você pode ter dois Ricardos no mesmo ambiente sem confusão, porque um é Oliveira e o outro é Silva.

Tendo entendido qual a utilidade, vamos entender como funciona no PHP. Em linguagens como Java, Actionscript e C# os namespaces estão associados aos arquivos "nativamente", já no PHP isso não ocorre, você tem que usar `require` ou `include` manualmente, ou seja tenho que criar algo assim:

**foo.php**

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar;

class Baz
{
     public function hello()
     {
          echo 'Olá mundo!';
     }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Foo\Bar\Baz;

require 'foo.php';

$test = new Baz;
```

### O uso do "use"

O `use` não faz nada, mesmo com `spl`, no PHP ele serve somente para criar apelidos, por exemplo suponha que você tem duas classes que o nome é o mesmo, se fizer isto:

```
<?php

use Aa\Bb\MinhaClasse;
use Xx\Yy\MinhaClasse;
```

Na hora de usar `MinhaClasse` ele iria conflitar, então você pode usar assim:

```
<?php

use Aa\Bb\MinhaClasse;
use Xx\Yy\MinhaClasse as MinhaClass2;

$a = new MinhaClasse;
$b = new MinhaClasse2;
```

Ou seja no momento que usa isto:

```
<?php

use Foo\Bar\Baz;

$test = new Baz;
```

Você está apenas criando um "apelido rápido".

Existe também a possibilidade de usar diretamente:

```
<?php

$a = new \Aa\Bb\MinhaClasse;
$b = new \Xx\Yy\MinhaClasse;
```

Note que dentro de namespaces você pode adicionar outras, como funções e acredito que até executar algumas coisas, exemplo de funções:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar;

function file($path) { ... }
```

Desta maneira não irá conflitar com a função nativa do php chamada `file`:

```
file('oi.txt');
\Foo\Bar\file('oi.txt');
```

> Aproveite e leia sobre as funções nativas e namespaces aqui:
>
> [É necessário barra "\" no começo de funções nativas quando usamos namespace?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78007/3635)

### O SPL

O SPL é um conjunto de funções e classes nativas do PHP que foram criadas para resolver uma série de situações, como o PHP não carrega nativamente, mas é possivel usar o `spl_autload`, tal como expliquei aqui [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635), desta maneira os arquivos ficarão associados por divisão de pastas aos namespaces, de maneira semelhante as linguagens C#, Java e Actionscript3.

### Extras

Como o @WallaceMaxters explicou em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104479/3635, isso foi implementado desde o PHP5.3, ou seja bem antes do PHP7

O @rray também deu uma dica de como "escrever menos" (somente para o PHP7), assim você pode agrupar as classes de um namespace https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104426/3635, exemplo:

```
use Foo\Bar\DB\{Relaciona, NoSQL, LDAP};
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, lendo umas respostas aqui e na net, consegui entender bem o conceito.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a [**documentação oficial do PHP sobre namespaces**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php), é basicamente **uma forma de encapsular itens**.

Na prática, serve para organizar melhor o seu código, agrupando classes e evitando o conflito de nomes, como por exemplo, com classes de terceiros.

Você pode utilizá-lo para separar módulos, grupos de classes ou da forma que você entender que irá melhor organizar e encapsular o seu código.