# Qual é a finalidade do comando "use" e qual é a sua relação com funções anonimas?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Estou fazendo uns testes com uma API RESTFul que estou criando usando o micro-framework Slim, e numa dessas rotinas que é responsável por executar uma determinada ação me chamou a atenção um comando que eu não conhecia, que é o comando `use`.

Veja abaixo um exemplo do comando `use` em um método que retorna um JSON com os dados obtidos do banco:

```
//Listando todas pessoas
$app->get('/pessoas/', 
        function() use ($app) 
        {
            (new \controllers\Pessoa($app))->listar();            
        });
```

Este comando parece fazer parte da função anonima `function()` que é responsável pela rota:

```
http://localhost/RestApiEx/pessoas/
```

E o uso dele me deixou com as seguinte dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade do comando `use` e qual é a relação que ele tem com funções anonimas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `use` passa o valor de uma ou mais variáveis para o escopo da função anonima tornando este valor acessível (herdando a variável), por exemplo se fizer isso:

```
<?php

$a = 'Olá, mundo!';

$foo = function() {
   echo $a;
};

$foo();
```

Vai acusar que a variável não foi definida, algo como:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: a in exemplo.php on line 6

Mas se fizer isto:

```
<?php

$a = 'Olá, mundo!';

$foo = function() use ($a) {
   echo $a;
};

$foo();
```

Será impresso o valor `'Olá, mundo!'`

No framework `Slim` a principal variável da aplicação é o `$app`, mas para torna-la acessível ao escopo da função anonima é necessário o `use`, se fizesse isto:

```
$app->get('/pessoas/', 
        function() 
        {
            (new \controllers\Pessoa($app))->listar();            
        });
```

Teria um erro semelhante:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: app in exemplo.php on line 9

E o seu controlador iria obter um valor `null` ao invés do objeto `new \Slim\App;`

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

### Extras

1. Um detalhe, ao usar `use` a variavel `$a` do exemplo não é uma [referencia](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), se fizer algo como:

   ```
   <?php

   $a = 1;

   $foo = function() use ($a) {
      $a += 10;
   };

   $foo();

   echo $a;
   ```

   Será exibido:

   > 1

   Mas se fizer a referencia:

   ```
   <?php

   $a = 1;

   $foo = function() use (&$a) {
      $a += 10;
   };

   $foo();

   echo $a;
   ```

   Será exibido 11:

   > 11
2. Algo importante a se notar é que no PHP existe outro `use`, que é usado para criar apelidos para classes, assim:

   ```
   <?php

   use Foo\Bar\Baz; //é possivel chamar new Baz, sem o namespace completo
   use Foo\Bar\Baz as Test; //é possivel chamar new Test para se referir ao Foo\Bar\Baz
   ```

   Leia mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151492/3635

Comment: Acho que no caso do exemplo do `Slim`, poderia haver também um exemplo sem o erro com o uso do ùse`,  para melhor entendimento.

Comment: @MagicHat como assim?

Comment: Você deu um exemplo usando como referência o framework `Slim`, mas no seu exemplo não há o uso do operador `use`, o que gera um erro, como seria o exemplo com o uso do `use`...

Comment: @MagicHat é porque já tem o exemplo na pergunta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172133/3635), o contexto foi explicar o que aconteceria se eu removesse ;)

Comment: Pode ser difícil de acreditar, mas antes de eu colocar o comentário eu vi e logo me veio a cabeça : "putz inglês e eu ainda tenho que ler tudo até achar o exemplo"....hehe tavez se o link levasse direto pro `#id` do exemplo..

Comment: @MagicHat eu coloco o link da doc em ingles, pois a doc do php é comunitária, então a versão em ingles é melhor mantida, já a versão em portugues é cheia de gafes, eu prefiro o link em ingles que ensina correto ao em portugues que ensina errado ;D

Comment: Posso usar o `use` para passar o valor da variável para função, mas não irá alterar o valor da mesma, ok. Mas se eu fizer a referência `&`, aí sim altero seu valor. Qual a diferença em usar o `use` com referência para alterar o valor da "variável externa", de passar uma propriedade para função, dar o `return` setando ela mesma? Teria vantagens em organização ou execução, ou temos casos que só usando o `use` e referência daria certo?

Comment: @rbz o use não tem nada haver com a referencia, o use apenas "copia" os valores pra dentro do escopo de uma função anonima/lambda, veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/kpcLO5

Comment: Sim, até aí ok, que foi até aqui: "Posso usar o use para passar o valor da variável para função, mas não irá alterar o valor da mesma, ok. Mas se eu fizer a referência &, aí sim altero seu valor.". A dúvida é mais do "por que/quando" usar o `use` com ou sem referência, se comparando se eu posso passar como propriedade da função. Se há casos que só funcionaria com o `use` com ou sem referência, ou só referência, ou se é só outra forma de fazer...