# Entendendo parâmetros e argumentos em funções

Tags: php, javascript, funções, parâmetros

Estou aprendendo programação e sei que existem algumas respostas sobre este tema, que já me fizeram (teoricamente) entender quem é o **parâmetro** e quem é o **argumento**, entretanto ainda não entendo o seguinte:

Se eu posso fazer isso:

```
<?php
function funcParm(){
    $foo = "parâmetro";
    echo "$foo";
}
funcParm();
?>
```

Por que fazer isso?

```
<?php
function funcParm2($foo){
    echo "$foo";
}
funcParm("parâmetro");
?>
```

E ainda como esses parâmetros se relacionam entre si em múltiplas funções ou funções aninhadas?

Nesse exemplo abaixo minha dúvida real seria respondida através de um teste de mesa, mas para não parecer preciosismo, se possível algumas informações que me indiquem a relação dos parâmetros e argumentos das funções pra que eu possa realizar o teste.

```js
function send(name) {
    // Local variable 'name' is stored in the closure
    // for the inner function.
    return function () {
        sendHi(name);
    }
}

function sendHi(msg) {
    console.log('Hello ' + msg);
}

var func = send('Bill');
func();
// Output:
// Hello Bill
sendHi('Pete');
// Output:
// Hello Pete
func();
// Output:
// Hello Bill
```

Comment: Tem alguma coisa mais que acha que precisa melhorar nas respostas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entenda que você só irá criar uma função se necessário, ou seja se a função for executada mais de uma vez (esse é um exemplo de cenário mais comum, existem outros), o argumento é se o valor é dinamico, só irá fazer isso provavelmente se o valor for fixo:

```
function funcParm(){
    $foo = "parâmetro";
    echo "$foo";
}
funcParm();
```

E fará isso se o valor for dinâmico:

```
function funcParm2($foo){
    echo "$foo";
}
funcParm("foo");
funcParm("bar");
funcParm("baz");
```

Posso presumir que *parâmetros* e *argumentos* em funções ou métodos **são a mesma coisa** e isso `$foo = "parâmetro";` não é um parâmetro de fato, mas sim é uma variável.

JavaScript diferentemente do PHP, consegue trabalhar múltiplos escopos, ou seja quando faz isso:

```
function send(name) {
    // Local variable 'name' is stored in the closure
    // for the inner function.
    return function () {
        sendHi(name);
    }
}
```

O argumento `name` **cascateia** para a sua função anonima que está dentro de `return`, isso é porque o Javascript funciona assim, outro exemplo para entender como o escopo funciona no Javascript, seria isso:

```js
function foo(a) {
   var b = 2;

   function bar() {
       //Consegue pegar o valor de foo
       console.log("função bar:", a, b);
   };

   var baz = function() {
       //Consegue pegar o valor de foo
       console.log("função anonima setada na variavel baz:", a, b);
   };

   bar();
   baz();

   return function() {
       //Consegue pegar o valor de foo
       console.log("função anonima no retorno da função foo():", a, b);
   };
}

(foo(2017))();
```

Veja que todas funções escritas **dentro** de `foo` podem acessar as variáveis.

No PHP a única maneira de fazer isso é usar [`global $variavel;`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) (o que expõe a todos lugares uma variável), constantes com [`define('<nome>', '<valor>');`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php), usar uma [*superglobal*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) ou simplesmente usar o `use`:

```
function send($name) {
    return function () use ($name) {
        sendHi($name);
    }
}
```

Como expliquei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172134/3635

### Referencias

No Javascript parametros (argumentos) são passados como valores, ou seja se fizer isso ele vai retornar `undefined`:

```js
function foobar(valor)
{
   setTimeout(function () {
       console.log(valor);
   }, 10);
}

var var1, var2;

foobar(var1);
foobar(var2);

var1 = 1000;
var2 = 2000;
```

Mas se passar um objeto ele receberá como **"referencia"**:

```js
function foobar(valor)
{
   setTimeout(function () {
       console.log(valor.name);
   }, 10);
}

var var1 = {}, var2 = {};

foobar(var1);
foobar(var2);

var1.name = 1000;
var2.name = 2000;
```

No PHP para usar referencias pode-se passar um objeto (uma classe por exemplo) ou usar o `&` (E comercial), assim:

```
function foo(&$referencia) {
    $referencia *= 1002;
}

$valorinicial = 2;

foo($valorinicial);

//Note que aqui o valor foi alterado (saída será 2004)
echo $valorinicial;
```

Veja um exemplo online: http://ideone.com/FQMPvi

Answer (score 4):

Quando faz

```
function funcParm() {
    $foo = "parâmetro";
    echo "$foo";
}
```

na prática está fazendo um [procedimento e não uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101), apesar de ser declarada assim.

## Qual o motivo de ter um procedimento?

Evitar repetições de código, ou pelo menos organizar um conjunto de instruções contidas em um só lugar dando um nome para isso. Como este nome pode se referir a ele em algum ponto do código pelo nome e o que está lá dentro será executado.

A utilidade é reduzida se vai usar apenas uma vez, mas ainda assim pode ser útil para dar uma responsabilidade separada, documentar melhor que aquelas instruções fazem parte de uma coisa só. Em exemplos abstratos assim nem sempre fica claro isso.

Se vai usar mais de uma vez o mesmo código há a vantagem óbvia de não ter que repetir o que já foi escrito e possivelmente estará fazendo algo mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), que é uma característica desejável de [código elegante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173216/101).

A grande diferença para uma função é que esta última deveria retornar um valor. Não tem problema chamar isso de função, todo mundo entende, mas formalmente ela não é bem uma função.

Note que no exemplo a variável é totalmente desnecessária. De qualquer forma ela é local, ela não é um parâmetro, seu valor é conhecido dentro do procedimento e apesar de poder variar, só o fará dentro dele, não terá um valor que vem de fora.

## O que é parametrizar?

Existem casos que cada vez que chamar um procedimento, quer que esse conjunto de instruções sejam executadas, mas uma pequena porção do código é um pouco diferente. Ou seja, tem uma lacuna nele que deve ser preenchida em cada execução. É uma parte **variável** do código, justamente porque varia em cada chamada. Mais ainda, quando você chamar o procedimento dirá qual é essa parte variável. Então o que fazemos é **parametrizar** a função.

Parâmetro é justamente uma variável que definirá alguma coisa.

> pa·râ·me·tro (para- + -metro) substantivo masculino
>
> 1. [Geometria]  Linha constante que entra na equação ou construção de uma curva, e serve de medida fixa para comparar as ordenadas e as
>    .abscissas.
> 2. Característica ou variável que permite definir ou comparar algo.
>
> "parâmetro", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/par%C3%A2metro [consultado em
> 05-01-2017].

Então quando chama o procedimento é passado um argumento, que é um valor que será atribuído à variável que serve como parâmetro. Para ajudar quem está chegando aqui e não sabe [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Isso dá uma flexibilidade no uso do código. Esse exemplo acima imprimirá sempre a mesma coisa. Já:

```
function funcParm2($foo) {
    echo "$foo";
}
funcParm("parâmetro");
```

está imprimindo esse texto neste exemplo. Se chamar como:

```
funcParm("outra coisa");
```

irá imprimir "outra coisa" literalmente :) Agora esse procedimento é mais útil porque ele serve para resolver o mesmo problema com informações diferentes em cada chamada sempre que necessário.

## Exemplo JavaScript

```js
function send(name) { //recebe um parâmetro que não deixa de ser uma variável
    return function() { //ainda estamos dentro da outra função
        sendHi(name); //aquela variável é acessível aqui
    }
}
//este é um caso diferente é uma variável que se mantêm dentro do escopo

function sendHi(msg) {
    console.log('Hello ' + msg);
}

var func = send('Bill'); //aqui a variável recebe como valor uma função
func(); //chama a variável como a função
sendHi('Pete'); // //chama diretamente a outra função
func();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/Parameters.js).

Aqui é uma questão de [escopo e tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101), não vou repetir aqui o que já está lá, mas a variável existe dentro da função toda, se tem uma função dentro dela, a variável continua existindo lá dentro, porque não saiu da função mais externa.

Ser um parâmetro ou uma variável local não muda nada. Talvez esteja fazendo duas perguntas em uma . Acho que aqui quer saber mais [como funciona uma função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101). Veja também [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101). E sobre o [*hoisting*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171327/101).

## Conclusão

Parâmetro é uma variável que receberá um valor durante a chamada da "função", portanto algo variará durante a execução.

Obviamente esse exemplo não ajuda entender tanto assim o uso de procedimentos (ou mesmo funções). Trocar uma execução simples por outra traz pouca vantagem, mas até pode trazer. Aí já entra no assunto de abstração que acho que não cabe aqui. A pergunta é interessante porque a maioria dos programadores sabe criar uma função/procedimento, mas não sabe bem para que ela serve de fato, e quando ela é útil ou não.