# Qual a diferença entre App\Http\Requests e Request

Tags: php, laravel

Qual diferença no Laravel, de utilizar `use App\Http\Requests` para `use Request`?

Comment: Se deve estar falando do `FormRequest` que fica dentro do `namespace App\Http\Requests` que são criados na sua aplicação (pelo comando `php artisan make:request`) e do `Request`  que é do `namespace Illuminate\Http\Request` que são relacionados, só que o primeiro tem o fator de validação embutido no código.

Answer (score 4):

O `use Request` não vai funcionar no Laravel, creio que seria algo como:

```
use App\Http\Requests as Request
```

Se é que o nome é `App\Http\Requests`, se o nome for `App\Http\Request` (sem `s`) basta uasr `use App\Http\Requests;` que poderá chamar em teu script apenas isto:

```
new Request;
```

O `use` não é para importar bibliotecas ou classes e sim para criar apelidos para os namespaces, como eu expliquei em:

- [Namespaces e Use quando usar e para que servem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151492/3635)
- [Qual é a finalidade do comando “use” e qual é a sua relação com funções anonimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172134/3635)

Então para detalhar um pouco mais, se fizer isto especificamente no Laravel:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Requests as Request;
```

Você estará criando o apelido `Request` para o namespace e classe `App\Http\Requests`

Se fizer isto:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Requests;
```

Você estará criando o apelido `Requests` (com `s`) para o namespace e classe `App\Http\Requests`, o objetivo dos apelidos é o mesmo de todas linguagens de programação que usam namespace, é criar permitir provavelmente digitar menos e usar duas classes que tenham o mesmo nome, mas namespaces diferentes, então por exemplo isto causaria erro, pois conflitaria:

```
<?php

use Foo\Bar\Baz;
use Foo2\Bar2\Baz;
```

Mas se fizer isto:

```
<?php

use Foo\Bar\Baz;
use Foo2\Bar2\Baz as Baz2;
```

E poderá usar assim:

```
$x = new Baz;
$y = new Baz2;
```

Comment: EU vi em algumas perguntas que tem sim uma diferença, mas infelizmente fico confuso, segue o link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/use-apphttprequests-or-illuminatehttprequest-which-should-it-be

Comment: @BiaBaldasso vou ler sobre o Laravel, eu só usei o basico dele até hoje, mas conforme o Virgilio especificamente no Laravel existem detalhes da "arquitetura", vou ajustar a resposta e lhe aviso ;)

Comment: Certo, pois o use Request funciona sim no Laravel.... Por isso a dúvida...

Answer (score 0):

> Qual diferença no Laravel, de utilizar `use App\Http\Requests` para `use Request`

Não existe uma classe chamada `App\Http\Requests`. Esse é um *namespace* criado dentro da sua aplicação ao usar o comando `php artisan make:request` e com ele você consegue criar [*Form Requests*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation) para pré validar as *requests* que chegarão ao seus *controllers*.

Você deve estar se confundindo com `Illuminate\Http\Request`, que é a classe responsável por manipular as *request* nos *controllers* do Laravel.

A diferença entre `Illuminate\Http\Request` e o `Request` é **nenhuma** :)

Mas de onde vem esse `Request`?

O Laravel cria um alias para algumas *facades* dentro do `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
],
```

Esse *facade* por sua fez chama o mesmo `Illuminate\Http\Request` a partir do [*Service Container*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container) do Laravel.

Para evitar de fazer mais de uma viagem entre uma *facade* e o [*Service Container*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container), prefira utilizar diretamente o `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Particularmente não gosto da ideia dos alias dentro do `config/app.php`. O código fica dependente de uma classe que só existe virtualmente dentro do *framework* e pode levar a esse tipo de mal entendido sobre qual classe utilizar.