# Duvida de declaração de atributos no PHP 7

Tags: php

Estou fazendo a migração do PHP 5 para o 7 e uma das mudanças foi que as variáveis globais pararam de existir. E possuo duas variáveis desse estilo em meu código:

```
$root = $GLOBALS['files']['siteRoot'];
$root = str_replace("//", "/", $root);
$pastas[] = "";
$pastas[] = "/controle/";
$pastas[] = "/pagseguro/";
$pastas[] = "/controle/auxiliar/";
$pastas[] = "/persistencia/";
$pastas[] = "/persistencia/DTO/";
$pastas[] = "/view/";
$pastas[] = "/view/classes/";
$pastas[] = "/view/relatorios/";
$pastas[] = "/library/";
$pastas[] = "/library/zip/";
$pastas[] = "/library/phpmailer/";

spl_autoload_register($nomeDaClasse) {
    globals $root, $pastas;
    $file = "";
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($pastas); $index++) {
        if (file_exists($root . $pastas[$index] . $nomeDaClasse . '.php')) {
            $file = $root . $pastas[$index] . $nomeDaClasse . '.php';
        }
    }
    if ($file == "") {
        return false;
    }
    include $file;
}
```

Me recomendaram a utilização do static mas não sei a forma de declarar as mesmas.

Comment: Variáveis estáticas e variáveis globais são conceitualmente distintas e uma não substitui a outra. Você usa a estrutura `globals` para importar para o contexto atual algo que foi definido em um contexto externo. Você tem maneiras mais elegantes de fazer o mesmo, tal como passar os valores por parâmetros se for uma função. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e apresentar o escopo completo de onde está utilizando tais variáveis?

Comment: Esse é todo o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, fazer:

```
spl_autoload_register($nomeDaClasse) {
    ...
}
```

Está errado e não faz sentido algum. A função [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php) é nativa do PHP e tem como objetivo registrar funções para o *autoload*. No trecho acima você não está nem chamando a função, nem definindo-a novamente. Ou seja, a sintaxe está completamente errada. Se tem dificuldades em visualizar isso, recomendo fortemente que revise a parte que mostra como chamar uma função e como defini-la.

O que você deve fazer é chamar a função e definir outra para ser registrada:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($nomeDaClasse) {
    ...
});
```

Note que agora o código é `spl_autoload_register(X)`, onde `X` é uma função anônima. Esta função anônima que será registrada no *autoload*. Você pode também fazer, caso preferir:

```
function minha_autoload($nomeDaClasse) {
    ...
}

spl_autoload_register('minha_autoload');
```

O resultado será o mesmo que utilizando a função anônima.

Ok, mas como passar os valores para escopo da função? Se for uma função anônima, você pode utilizar o `use` que serve justamente para isso:

```
$root = 1;
$pastas = 2;

spl_autoload_register(function ($nomeDaClasse) use ($root, $pastas) {
    // $root e $pastas existirão aqui com os mesmos valores
    ...
});
```

Onde `$root` e `$pastas` são variáveis definidas no mesmo escopo em que foi definida a função anônima.

- [Qual é a finalidade do comando "use" e qual é a sua relação com funções anonimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172133/5878)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou com toda certeza rever a parte de chamadas de funções. É uma linguagem nova para mim e estou ainda penando um pouco para dominá-la