# Laravel Eloquet AND-OR-AND Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma função no repository para listar apenas os funcionários não demitidos em uma determinada data

uso ParameterGroup, mas a condição não encontra o parâmetro $data da função, dando o erro:
"Undefined variable: data"

```
public function listarFuncionariosAtivos($data) 
{
    $funcionarios = Funcionario::where('demitido', '0')
                              ->orWhere(function($query) {
                                  $query->whereNotNull('data_demissao')
                                        ->where('data_demissao', '>=', $data);
                              })
                        ->orderBy('nome')
                        ->get(['id','nome','salario','data_admissao','data_demissao']); 

    return $funcionarios;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O escopo das variaveis no PHP não são acessiveis em sub-funções, você deve usar o `use ()` para acessar as variaveis de um "escopo acima":

```
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($data) {
    $query->whereNotNull('data_demissao')
          ->where('data_demissao', '>=', $data);
```

Como respondi em [Qual é a finalidade do comando “use” e qual é a sua relação com funções anonimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172134/3635)

Comment: Obrigada, resolvido!