# Como acessar uma classe que está dentro de uma pasta no vendor Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Não consigo acessar a classe do spreadsheet, aparece:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class Excel extends Model
{
    public function excelPropostas($ini = null, $fim = null, $qtd = null)
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        ...
    }
}
```

Classe do Spreaadsheet:

```
namespace PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet;

class Spreadsheet
{
..
}
```

porém dá erro:

```
Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se tu instalou pelo composer, era só ter usado o namespace `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet`, sem esse `Vendor` no inicio, outra coisa não mova suas dependência para fora da pasta vendor do projeto, além disso o namespace de um arquivo não depende da localização dele no diretório e sim de qual é o namespace usado no arquivo que tu ta importanto, por convenção é utilizado o mesmo namespace referente a hierarquia de diretórios. Recomendo pesquisar melhor sobre namespace em php. [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151487/namespaces-e-use-quando-usar-e-para-que-servem](aqui).

Comment: Eu dei uma editada na pergunta, de fato ele o diretório, porém ainda assim, ele não acha a classe. A não ser que o problema seja para carregar ela no formato Model do próprio Laravel.

Comment: Tu instalou ele pelo composer?

Comment: Sim, instalei pelo composer.

Comment: Recomendo remover a pasta vendor do projeto e instalar novamente, e depois disso gerar o autoload denovo, da seguinte forma:
Remova a pasta vendor `rm -rf vendor` depois instale as dependências `composer install` e por ultimo `composer dump-autoload`. E já dou a dica nunca altere manualmente nenhum arquivo dentro do diretório vendor, isso só trara problemas futuros.

Comment: O erro é na chamada da classe: $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

Essa pasta não é nativa do laravel, então não adianta eu reinstalar. Mas vou tentar dump-autoload.

Comment: Não funcionou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não achei uma forma de resolver isso manualmente, a não ser manipulando um arquivo em um diretório fora do laravel.
No entanto achei esse serviço na web, já testei e funciona:
https://laravel-excel.com/