# Utilização do new Class() ou invés de new \Namespace\Class() no autoload do PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, composer

Estou enfrentando um problema para manusear as minhas classes com o `composer autoload`.

Todas as chamadas são feitas através do JQuery, após, ele chama um documento PHP que deverá montar a página de classes e fazer a chamada da função que preciso.

Exemplo:

Possuo uma página de login, quando preencho todos os campos ele fará a chamada através do arquivo que está em JS.

Exemplo do `button`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-login" id="btn-login" onclick="JavaScript:getClasseLogin().fazerLogin()">
    Entrar
</button>
```

Quando ele faz a chamada do `getClasseLogin().fazerLogin()`, tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, ele consegue chamar a URL normalmente, segue código:

```
fazerLogin: function () {
        $("#btn-login").click(function () {
            var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'classes/retorna_metodo_ajax.php?classe=Cliente&metodo=validaUsuario',
                data : data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $("#btn-login").html('Validando ...');
                },
                success :  function(response){
                    if(response.codigo == "1"){
                        console.log("entra no if");
                        $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                        $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
                        window.location.href = "home.php";
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("entra no else");
                        $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                        $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
                        $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

O problema todo começa agora...

A URL que ele está enviando é a seguinte:

https://jkads.com.br/bootstrap/classes/retorna_metodo_ajax.php?classe=Clientes&metodo=validaUsuario

Aí dentro ele passa para o documento `retornar_metodo_ajax.php`, que está desta forma:

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
ob_start();
//$params = $_GET['params'];
$classe = $_GET['classe'];
$metodo = $_GET['metodo'];
var_dump($classe);
var_dump($metodo);
if($classe == null || $metodo == null) {
    die("Não possui classe ou método");
} else {
    $_nome = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET["classe"]), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    if (!file_exists($classe . ".php")) {
        die("Classe não encontrada.");
    }
    $_class = new $classe();
    echo $_class->$metodo();
}
```

Ele entra no documento, consegue fazer as devidas verificações, mas quando ele tenta inserir a classe ele retorna o erro:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'Clientes' not found in **/home/jkadsco1/domains/jkads.com.br/public_html/bootstrap/classes/retorna_metodo_ajax.php on** line **18**

O documento `Clientes.php` é este:

```
<?php

namespace Clientes;

class Clientes {

    function __construct()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function validaUsuario($params)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Chegou aqui também')</script>";
        $parametros = explode(",", json_decode($params));
        echo "<script>alert(".$parametros.")</script>";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Ele não consegue chamar a classe, pois infelizmente, todas as vezes que eu vou fazer a utilização de uma classe em um documento, preciso utilizar como abaixo:

```
$cliente = new \Clientes\Clientes();
$cliente->validaUsuario();
```

Quando o documento `retorna_metodo_ajax.php` tenta fazer o `new()` ele não está conseguindo, pois não consegue encontrar sem especificar como `new \Namespace\Classe()`.

Há alguma forma de fazer com que toda vez que eu chamar o `new Class()` ele apenas chame pela classe especificada ao invés de `new \Namespace\Class()`?

Já tentei dar um `include()` com o documento da classe, mas não funciona. Tentar concatenar como `$_class = new "\\".$classe."\\".$classe()` também não funcionou.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz com isso?

---

Estrutura das pastas:

```
.
├── classes
│   ├── BaseBD.php
│   ├── BdMySql.php
│   ├── Cadastro.php
│   ├── classNoticias.php
│   ├── Clientes.php
│   ├── conec.php
│   ├── ConecxaoBd.php
│   ├── conexao.php
│   ├── Datas.php
│   ├── funcoesGerais.php
│   ├── Globals.php
│   ├── GravarLogs.php
│   ├── Menus.php
│   ├── News.php
│   ├── Noticias.php
│   └── retorna_metodo_ajax.php
│
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── index.php
└── vendor
    └── autoload.php
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "classes"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sobre `new Class()` ao invés de `new \Namespace\Class()`, se não quer namespaces então não escreva com namespaces em nada, já resolve, mas se o que quer é usar namespaces com "apelidos" então leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151492/3635

Comment: Agora eu tenho uma duvida, pra que tanto OOP em algo simples, em algo que na verdade dava pra fazer de forma simples, entendível e organizada que não precise de OOP. O OOP sem necessidade real é apenas um desperdicio, a maioria usa, mas não por necessidade, foi pq alguém lhes contou uma FAKENEWS, *"OOP é melhor"*. "Melhor" depende de contexto e para o seu caso não melhora em nada, ao contrário, complica, é desnecessário e nem visa entender ou funcionar como OO. Muitos também usam OO sem necessidade para fazer algo parecer mais elegante, o que acaba sendo uma armadilha.

Comment: É um projeto para a faculdade, preciso fazer um sistema inteiro utilizando OO, caso contrário não será aceito. Como foi especificado que tudo deverá passar por "globais" JS e ser enviado para o mesmo documento, tratado e enviado para a classe, preciso seguir esta especificação :/

Comment: As faculdades então não andam boas de professores, ensinando OOP para não OO, quero dizer escrever em OO não necessariamente é uma *"orientação a objetos"*, na prática é de funcionar, na realidade você não está fazendo nada que seja realmente com o propósito da existência do OO, afinal quando o OO foi criado ele tinha um motivo para existir, e no seu caso caso não está nem seguindo isto. Mas a critica sobre isto é a parte, sobre o seu problema eu deixei no primeiro comentário.

Comment: infelizmente tenho que concordar... Meu professor é do tipo "tenho meus preferidos, o resto se vira"... O conteúdo dele é fraco, mas infelizmente uma faculdade de qualidade é muito mais cara... Em relação a dúvida, eu li o seu post lá, estou tentando fazer ele funcionar aqui, mas ainda diz que não encontra a classe... Fiz o teste chamando uma função pelo `new Class()` e está funcionando, retirei o `use()` e o `namespace()` dos documentos e agora está funcionando fazer a chamada, porém, pelo `retorna_metodo_ajax.php` ele ainda não está conseguindo fazer a chamada da função

Comment: Em autoload acho errado e desnecessário usa `    if (!file_exists($classe . ".php")) {
        die("Classe não encontrada.");
    }`, quando uma classe é inacessivel o unico erro deveria ser o que já esta ocorrendo, essa dupla checagem que você fez só toma mais tempo do script e realmente nem precisaria existir. Só pra constar, se esta usando `vendor/autoload.php` significa que está usando composer, estou correto? Existe um `composer.json` na sua pasta?

Comment: Sim existe, quando eu indaguei em sala sobre isso, praticamente o que tu disseste, ele só me respondeu que sabia o que estava fazendo, que 15 anos de experiência falavam por si só... Mas enfim... Sim, existe o `composer.json`

Comment: **Então o problema esta na configuração do composer.json**, se não configurar corretamente nele as suas classes customizadas não serão encontradas... A pessoa pode ter 20 anos de experiência e ainda sim ter aprendido tudo errado, mas realmente a experiência faz diferença sim, claro que se for humilde e aceitar q um meio anterior de fazer as coisas estava errado e deseja mudar, manter um certo nivel de ceticismos quando alguém vem com uma solução mágica tentando lhe convencer a usa-la e sem nenhum argumento técnico. A evolução parte de cada um, mas gosto de ajudar os outros a trilharem melhor.

Comment: Cara... Gostaria que meu professor falasse contigo kkkk, ele realmente tem muita experiência, mas ao meu ver, se ele continuar como está, logo vai acabar perdendo o emprego, por que 80% da turma está puta pelo fato de ter um conhecimento médio/avançado e estar ali apenas por conta do certificado e ter que ouvir estas coisas dele... Eu vou ver a configuração ele certinho pra poder terminar isso logo hahaha

Comment: Coloca a estrutura das pastas que usa semelhante a isto https://cmatskas.com/generate-ascii-folder-structures-for-windows-with-tree/ na pergunta, mas com as suas pastas é claro, não precisa usar o programa indicado de gerar, só copia e cola e ajusta como estão as suas pastas e copia o conteudo do composer.json e põe na pergunta também, tenho certeza que assim poderei lhe ajudar.

Comment: Adicionei a estrutura de pastas, pelo ubuntu fica mais simples, basta utilizar o `tree` dentro da pasta :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104102/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-programmer-br).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, respondi no chat pra ti