# mysql com resultado unico em PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

Estou tentando criar uma consulta da seguinte forma:

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com essa estrutura:

> nome | endereco | status

O campo status só possui 2 tipos de valores 1 ou 0. Eu quero contar todos registros que estejam com o status 0

Fiz a seguinte query:

```
select count(*) as total from sv_mensagens where status = 0
```

Em PHP eu fiz o seguinte código usando PDO:

```
$this->pdo = ConnDB::conexao();

$query3 = "select count(*) as total from sv_mensagens where status = 0";
$conta2 = $this->pdo->prepare($query3);
$conta2->execute();

while ($result = $conta2->fetchAll()){
    echo $result['total'];
}
```

só que ocorre erro e não funciona o que eu quero trazer é o resultado da contagem de todos os registros que estiverem com o status em 0.

Comment: Qual erro é? poderia colocara mensagem?

Comment: Tentei melhorar a pergunta, ficar mais fácil de entender, caso ache melhor voltar para a antiga, basta clicar [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/188252/revisions) e clicar em  `reverter`

Comment: A `query` quando executada no Mysql funciona normalmente?

Comment: obrigado bonifazio fique a vontade obrigado mesmo :D

Answer (score 1):

Você está chamando a função [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) dentro de um loop.

A função `fetchAll` vai retornar um array com todos os resultados.

No seu caso, deve estar retornando o seguinte array:

```
$resultado = array(
  array(
    'total' => 'Algum Numero'
  )
);
```

Experimente usar a função [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). Note que você também deve passar o tipo de Fetch que você quer.

O código final ficaria assim:

```
$this->pdo = ConnDB::conexao();

$query3 = "select count(*) as total from sv_mensagens where status = 0";
$conta2 = $this->pdo->prepare($query3);
$conta2->execute();

$result = $conta2->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo $result[0]['total'];
```

Comment: @Bonifazio isso foi feito para evitar namespaces, se estiver dentro de uma namespace e não usar o \ pode dar problema. **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78007/3635

Comment: cara valeu mesmo deu certinho o que eu queria muito obrigado pela grande ajuda obrigado mesmo que deus te abençoe.

Comment: o meu aqui ta com namespace e ta funcionando de boa

Comment: @mfurlan, aproveite que você é novo e de uma passada no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Você quer pegar o resultado no php e fazer mais condições? Se for isso, basta atribuir a uma variavel a utilizar: `$meuValor = $result[0]['total'];`

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
 select count(status) as total from sv_mensagens where status = 0
```